# settings by using onBuildHeaders don't work on Ice cream Sandwich

Tags: android, settings, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have an application that works on Honeycomb. It shows the Settings by using `onBuildHeaders` and `PreferenceFragment`.
I run it on `Galaxy Nexus sdk 4.0 ( Icecream Sandwich)` and it does not work. The main screen is shown correctly but when I click on a raw nothing happens: the platform clicks and shows the selection but the `PreferenceFragment` is not shown.

Have you seen this problem too?

Comment: I saw that onCreate of the PreferenceFragment is not even called. I renamed the PreferenceFragment classes in the .java files and I left the old names in the settings-header.xml and the VM doesn't complain: it looks like it is not even trying to look for the PreferenceFragment referenced in the xml

Comment: I also checked that an Intent is received by onNewIntent of my PreferenceActivity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cmp=com.myapp.comp.android/.ui.settings.fragment.SettingsActivity (has extras) } extra=Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=564]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to remove the `singleTop` option in the `AndroidManifest` for the `SettingsActivity` (`PreferenceActivity` that loads the headers)